# How does mobx prevent rerender children of observable components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I've found mobx observable component only rerender themselves and not their children. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 1):

From the MobX documentation:

> MobX reacts to any an existing observable property that is read during the execution of a tracked function.

By using `@observer` over a component MobX will track and react to changes occurred to observables defined inside the render function of this component.
Each child component should be wrapped with `@observer` if you wish it to react to changes.

---

**Edited:**

By using `observer` over a component, MobX will override the `shouldComponentUpdate` by telling the component to update only when necessary (observables change or shallow props change).

From MobX `@observer` [documentation](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observer-component.html):

> observer also prevents re-renderings when the props of the component have only shallowly changed, which makes a lot of sense if the data passed into the component is reactive. This behavior is similar to React PureRender mixin, except that state changes are still always processed. If a component provides its own shouldComponentUpdate, that one takes precedence.See for an explanation this [github issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/101)

Comment: Thanks but this isn't answering the question. I'm asking how it prevents the rerender of child components as that's the normal `React` behavior.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood you, I'm updating my answer.